# how to use ng-repeat according to the different type of category in array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i have sample data array like this 
lets focus on description key 
you can see in this array containt 3 objects but descriptions are oly two types (description1 and description2 )
i need to generate div s according to this description key 
in this case i need two div s description1 and description2 
how can i do this

```
var apps = [
{
  name: 'Azurite',
  description: "description1",
  shine: 8,
  price: 110.50,
  rarity: 7,
  color: '#CCC',
  faces: 14,
  images: [
    "img/01.png",
    "img/02.png",
    "img/03.png"

  ],
  reviews: [{
    stars: 5,
    body: "I love this gem!",
    author: "joe@example.org",
    createdOn: 1397490980837
  }, {
    stars: 1,
    body: "This gem sucks.",
    author: "tim@example.org",
    createdOn: 1397490980837
  }]
},
{
  name: 'Bloodstone',
  description: "description2",
  shine: 9,
  price: 22.90,
  rarity: 6,
  color: '#EEE',
  faces: 12,
  images: [
    "img/04.png",
    "img/05.png",
    "img/06.png"
  ],
  reviews: [{
    stars: 3,
    body: "I think this gem was just OK, could honestly use more shine, IMO.",
    author: "JimmyDean@example.org",
    createdOn: 1397490980837
  }, {
    stars: 4,
    body: "Any gem with 12 faces is for me!",
    author: "gemsRock@example.org",
    createdOn: 1397490980837
  }]
},{
  name: 'sample ',
  description: "description1",
  shine: 9,
  price: 22.90,
  rarity: 6,
  color: '#EEE',
  faces: 12,
  images: [
     "img/07.png",
    "img/08.png",
    "img/09.png"
  ],
  reviews: [{
    stars: 3,
    body: "I think this gem was just OK, could honestly use more shine, IMO.",
    author: "JimmyDean@example.org",
    createdOn: 1397490980837
  }, {
    stars: 4,
    body: "Any gem with 12 faces is for me!",
    author: "gemsRock@example.org",
    createdOn: 1397490980837
  }]
}]
```

Comment: Do you mean the html differs depending on which description the object has?

Answer (score 2):

You need something like a `groupBy` filter, https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter implements one you could use. Simply add this module to your application dependencies (`angular.module('yourAppName', ['angular.filter']`) and use it on your `ng-repeat` expression:

```
<div ng-repeat="(description, apps) in apps | groupBy : 'description'"></div>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5uKHrSkKO5XBVjKraiYC?p=preview

Comment: exactly that's what i need superb great

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this without using any extra plugins by **creating different arrays for each descriptions of the main array in the controller using forEach function and then looping it through ng-repeat in your HTML**.

here is the working plunker

http://embed.plnkr.co/FXUJGnzkz1K9hL1t4uI1/preview

Hope this helps too